# "Generate Graph of Include Files" in Visual Studio 2017 not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Just downloaded Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and when I right click on any open .h or .cpp file, and select Generate Graph of Include Files, it does not generate anything! Is this a bug? Is something missing from the installation?
I have searched in MSDN forums and no one seems to have had this problem...

Thanks in advance!
Juan Dent

Comment: There is a recent bug report outstanding with MS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41410/generate-graph-of-include-files-still-not-working.html